# Rename fields in JOLT transformation

Tags: json, jolt

I want to change the name of fields in an array by Jolt. Please **explain how it works** with your answer.

**Input:**

```
{
    "referenceName": "***",
    "name": "***"
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
    "ReferenceName": "***",
    "ColumnName": "***"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this simple spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "referenceName": "ReferenceName",
      "name": "ColumnName"
    }
  }
]
```

**Or you can have simpler:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "r*": "R&(0,1)",
      "n*": "ColumnN&(0,1)"
    }
  }
]
```

When you want to change some names in your JSON, You can use the **`shift`** operation like the above spec:

1. **`r*`**: match all keys that started with the `r` like `referenceName` and `*` match everything after `r` that equals `eferenceName`. You can write `R&(0,1)` that `&(0,1)` value is equal to first `*`.
2. **`n*`**: match all keys that started with the `n` like `name` and `*` match everything after `n` that is equal to `ame`. You can write `ColumnN&(0,1)` that `&(0,1)` value is equal to first `*`.

**Note:** `&` means the key's value, But when you use the `&(0,1)`, you are saying that in the `0` level or current level please get the **first** `*` value. Suppose you had a **second** `*` in this level, You should get it like this: **`&(0,2)`**